# When does Stateless Session Bean pool initialization happens?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish-3, ejb-3.1

In my application I have a pool of "workers" implemented as SLSB.

I have defined in my `glassfish-ejb-jar.xml` some properties related to pool initialization like follows:

```
<glassfish-ejb-jar>
    <enterprise-beans>
        <ejb>
            <ejb-name>Worker</ejb-name>
            <jndi-name>Worker</jndi-name>
            <bean-pool>

                <steady-pool-size>10</steady-pool-size>
                <resize-quantity>2</resize-quantity>
                <max-pool-size>30</max-pool-size>
                <pool-idle-timeout-in-seconds>300</pool-idle-timeout-in-seconds>
            </bean-pool>
        </ejb>
    </enterprise-beans>
</glassfish-ejb-jar>
```

Actually the pool starts and is dimensioned properly.

The only point is that the initialization does not happen at startup but after a while.
This actually gives me some problems with clients trying to use the pool but finding it not initialized.

Is there any way to trigger the pool initialization at startup or this is entirely left to the container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I guess the issue is solved. 
Even I did not found any way to force pool initialization, I noticed that as soon as a Pool member is needed, the whole pool is loaded.

This sounds definitively "lazy" and even if it actually does not create any issue with the flow of my application, it definitively represent a performance issue since the pooled beans are quite heavy weight.

Answer (score 2):

> Q: Is there any way to trigger the pool initialization at startup or this
>   is entirely left to the container?

Yes. It depends on the version of Java EE you are using:

**Java EE 5 (EJB 3.0) and older** - use startup servlet, i.e. servlet that will have parameter `load-on-startup` set to 1 in `web.xml` configuration. In the `init` method of that servlet you will instantiate your Worker bean and everything will happen at startup. An example of servlet configuration:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyStartupServlet></servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>your.package.MyStartupServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

**Java EE 6 (EJB 3.1)** - use `@Startup` annotation with Singleton bean. From the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipvi.html):

> The EJB container is responsible for determining when to initialize a
>   singleton session bean instance unless the singleton session bean
>   implementation class is annotated with the javax.ejb.Startup
>   annotation. In this case, sometimes called eager initialization, the
>   EJB container must initialize the singleton session bean upon
>   application startup

Comment: Unfortunately they are not singletons. I'have actually a singleton annotated as @Startup for some initialization procedures, but these beans have to be pooled.

Comment: In that case, leave beans as they are (SLSB, pooled..) and use special singleton just for instantiation of them. They'll be ready now for your clients, but bear in mind that if they are not used for a while, container will remove them.